# VBA - Export excel charts to power point on same slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

```
Sub Export_Allcahrts_ppt()

Dim mypowerpoint As PowerPoint.Application

Set mypowerpoint = New PowerPoint.Application

mypowerpoint.Visible = msoTrue

Dim mypowerpoint_pres  As PowerPoint.Presentation

Set mypowerpoint_pres = mypowerpoint.Presentations.Add

Dim myslide  As PowerPoint.Slide

Set myslide = mypowerpoint_pres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)

Dim mychart  As ChartObject

Dim j As Long
j = 0
For Each mychart In Sheet1.ChartObjects
j = j + 1
Next


For Each mychart In Sheet1.ChartObjects

mychart.Copy

myslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteBitmap

myslide.Shapes(1).Top = 100

myslide.Shapes(1).Height = 200

myslide.Shapes(1).Left = 30

If mypowerpoint_pres.Slides.Count < j Then

Set myslide = mypowerpoint_pres.Slides.Add(mypowerpoint_pres.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutBlank)

Else

Exit Sub

End If

Next


End Sub
```

Comment: i have three three charts and three tables in sheet1 , please help to export all of them in single slide on power point using vba code , the code i had only exports charts to different slides ...thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't need to loop to get j; just use

```
j = Sheet1.ChartObjects.Count
```

But you also don't need j at all. What your code does is insert a new slide for each new chart if the number of slides does not yet equal the number of charts copied so far.

So try this slightly rearranged and streamlined code. I haven't tested it, but I don't think I've changed the syntax.

```
Sub Export_Allcahrts_ppt()
  Dim mypowerpoint As PowerPoint.Application
  Dim mypowerpoint_pres As PowerPoint.Presentation
  Dim myslide As PowerPoint.Slide
  Dim mychart As ChartObject
  Dim j As Long

  Set mypowerpoint = New PowerPoint.Application
  mypowerpoint.Visible = msoTrue

  Set mypowerpoint_pres = mypowerpoint.Presentations.Add

  Set myslide = mypowerpoint_pres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)

  j = Sheet1.ChartObjects.Count

  For Each mychart In Sheet1.ChartObjects
    mychart.Copy
    myslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteBitmap

    With myslide.Shapes(myslide.Shapes.Count)
      .Top = 100
      .Height = 200
      .Left = 30
    End With
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much jon Peltier.

i had new requirement where i need to select specific charts from different sheets and paste them on single slide in power point, it will be great help which resolves my most of the quiries...thanks again .